# Why does TypedQuery.getResultList() resolve every ManyToOne association with a seperate SELECT?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Considering the following simple entity association:
(EntityA) *-1 (EntityB)
made in database with a foreign key in EntityA (entityB_id).

The JPA Entities are mapping this relationship unidirectional:

```
@Entity
EntityA {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable=false,length=250)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    private EntityB entityB;

    ... getter/setter ...
}

@Entity
EntityB {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable=false,length=250)
    private String name;

    ... getter/setter ...
}
```

If a simple query is made:

```
EntityManager em = ...;
TypedQuery<EntityA> tq = em.createQuery("from EntityA a", EntityA.class);
tq.getResultList();
```

I see in the SQL debug output of Hibernate, that an EntityB query is done for every row of EntityA:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        entitya0_.id as id8_,
        entitya0_.entityB_id as entityB3_8_,
        entitya0_.name as name8_ 
    from
        EntityA entitya0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        entityb0_.id as id4_0_,
        entityb0_.name as name4_0_ 
    from
        EntityB entityb0_ 
    where
        entityb0_.id=?
```

Even if the default fetch strategy is EAGER (which seems to be the case), EntityB should be fetched via implizit join, shouldn't it?
What is wrong?

But it's getting even more weird - if only a single EntityA object is loaded:

```
EntityA a = em.find(EntityA.class, new Long(1));
```

Then Hibernate seems to understand the job:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        entitya0_.id as id1_1_,
        entitya0_.entityB_id as entityB3_1_1_,
        entitya0_.name as name1_1_,
        entityb1_.id as id12_0_,
        entityb1_.name as name12_0_ 
    from
        EntityA entitya0_ 
    inner join
        EntityB entityb1_ 
        on entitya0_.entityB_id=entityb1_.id 
    where
        entitya0_.id=?
```

The above tests have been made with Hibernate 3.5 and JPA 2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution that worked for the current use case is to include a fetch join in the statement:

```
select a from entityA left join fetch a.entityB
```

This will fetch all associated EntityBs (and override a FetchType.LAZY).

Answer (score 5):

> Even if the default fetch strategy is EAGER (which seems to be the case), EntityB should be fetched via implicit join, shouldn't it? What is wrong?

Indeed, the default `FetchType` of a `ManyToOne` is `EAGER`. But this just says that `One` side should get loaded **when** the `Many` side is loaded, not **how**. The how is left at the discretion of the persistence provider (and JPA doesn't allow to tune the strategy).

Hibernate has a specific `Fetch` annotations allowing to tune the fetching mode though. From the documentation:

> #### [2.4.5.1. Lazy options and fetching modes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-fetching)
>
> JPA comes with the fetch option to
>   define lazy loading and fetching
>   modes, however Hibernate has a much
>   more option set in this area. To fine
>   tune the lazy loading and fetching
>   strategies, some additional
>   annotations have been introduced:
>
> - [...]
> - `@Fetch`: defines the fetching strategy used to load the association.
>     `FetchMode` can be `SELECT` (a select is
>     triggered when the association needs
>     to be loaded), `SUBSELECT` (only
>     available for collections, use a
>     subselect strategy - please refers to
>     the Hibernate Reference Documentation
>     for more information) or `JOIN` (use a
>     SQL `JOIN` to load the association while
>     loading the owner entity). `JOIN`
>     overrides any lazy attribute (an
>     association loaded through a JOIN
>     strategy cannot be lazy).

You might want to try the following (if you don't mind using provider specific annotations):

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private EntityB entityB;
```

Comment: Thank you Pascal. This is exactly what i was looking for. I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry to say that, Pascal, but i get the same results wheter this annotation is used or not.

Comment: BTW I'm able to get the desired behaviour with the query 'select a from EntityA a left join fetch a.entityB'. But I wonder why hibernate doesn't do this by default (or if told to do so by annotations). Any ideas?

Comment: @Mulmoth: No need to sorry, I'm just pointing out that FetchType.EAGER + FetchMode.JOIN is *supposed* to work according to the documentation and forum threads such as [this one](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=970766). But this doesn't exclude any bug and I'm not responsible :) Looks like you're not [the only one](https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2378507) actually. Check Jira for existing issues and maybe submit one if required.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts, Pascal. It's my first project with JPA/Hibernate and I'm still wondering if i missunderstood something or did a mistake with my annotations. It is really surprising me that there is no intuitive solution for that standard case.

Comment: @Mulmoth: I can understand that, it's very disturbing when things aren't working as advertised, whether you're experienced with a tool or not (I had to double check to see if I didn't make a mistake with my suggestion and I believe I didn't). To sum up, your interrogations are IMO perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you even worrying about this? The point of using an ORM library is so you don't have to deal with details like this. If you see that some operation is running slowly, *then* you start thinking about optimizing queries.

I think that Hibernate's strategy makes sense, since the relationship is ManyToOne. This means that the number of EntityBs returned in the query will never be greater than the number of EntityAs, and will usually be less. So trying to fetch the data from EntityB via a join would probably mean sending redundant copies of the same data.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your answer. I'm new to Hibernate/JPA so i am - assuming this should be done in a more efficient way - wondering if i made a mistake with the annotations. In the real project, EntityA has three associations. Imaging a query that returns 100 EntityAs - with the described behaviour it would fetch 400 objects (with 301 SQL-Statements), propably without any need for it.

Comment: If you don't need the related entities, then you should mark the association as lazy. And you know what they say about assuming.

Comment: The queries are made even if the association is marked lazy. Moreover, i do need the associated objects.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was wrong - the queries are *not* made with FetchType.LAZY. But as i mentioned, i need the associated objects eagerly fetched in an effective way.